# Primitive type and wrapper class within method argument

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive

I'm very confused about a task that I'm required to do (Not asking for the answer, just a point in the right direction)

I basically need to create an add method for the following main method.  I'm confused though how to pass the arguments due to the fact they are mix a primitive and wrapper.  Any help would be good.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Double answer1 = add(2, 7);
   Number answer2 = add(new Integer(4), new Double(5.2));
   double answer3 = add(8, 1.3);
   System.out.println(answer1 + " " + answer2 + " " + answer3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I define a single method, for all your example then too it compiles and produce result as expected without any errors

```
public static double add(double i , double j)
{
   return i + j;
}
```

This phenomena of [Boxing Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is neatly handled by  Java compiler.